# How to fetch data from Angular JS forms

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have created a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/qbWBFo that shows a form that I am auto filling based on some json (keys). When the user hits submit, I need to access all data that was filled in and create a json like shown below. Obviously if the div named "myform.rows" had static fields I would be able to call $scope.myform.rows. and get all data. Any suggestions? Thank you

UPDATE: The json that I want to get when a user hits submit after filling out all the form fields is something like this:

```
{

  "Date Of Birth": {
          "value": "19 May, 1990",
          "tag": "a"
  },
  "Employer": {
          "value": "Starbucks",
          "tag": "b"
  },
  "First Name": {
          "value": "Jane",
          "tag": "a"
  },
  "Last Name":{
          "value": "Doe",
          "tag": "c"
  },
  "Middle Name": {
          "value": "K.",
          "tag": "c"
  },
  "Place Of Birth": {
          "value": "Houston, Texas",
          "tag": "d"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work for you:

`<input type="text" ng-model="formData[k]"/>`
Where `k` is the key/property of the JSON.

I have created Plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/hyBFpRr3OOtanuYsGibs

Comment: Thankyou. I left out crucial information. Please see the update above.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-model` on your form controls. This will automatically bind to same variable in your scope.

Say you start an object in scope: `$scope.myFormData={}`;

Then add to inputs `ng-model`;

```
<input ng-model="myFormData.name"/>
<input ng-model="myFormData.phone"/>
```

As user types the `myFormData` object will be automatically updated with whatever `ng-model`'s that match that object

Then within submit method, you send that object to server.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/DfBszy?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thankyou. I left out crucial information. Please see the update above.

Comment: what do you mean `please update the above`? Glad to help answer problems but this isn't a `code this for me` site

Comment: After seeing yours and vijay's response I realized that I left out crucial detail of what I was trying to get the final/result json to look like. And just to answer your concern, I am very new to AngularJS and if I was trying other people to do the code for me, I won't have bothered to set up a Plunker. Thanks for your time.

Comment: well try adapting what I gave you to your situation. WHen you run into problems can get more specific helping